# Index strings by letter including diacritics

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm not sure how to formulate this question, but I'm looking for a magic function that makes this code

```py
for x in magicfunc("H̶e̕l̛l͠o͟ ̨w̡o̷r̀l҉ḑ!͜"):
    print(x)
```

Behave like this:

```
H̶
e̕
l̛
l͠
o͟
 ̨
w̡
o̷
r̀
l҉
ḑ
!͜
```

Basically, is there a built in unicode function or method that takes a string and outputs an array per glyph with all their respective unicode decorators and diacritical marks and such? The same way that a text editor moves the cursor over to the next letter instead of iterating all of the combining characters.

If not, I'll write the function myself, no help needed. Just wondering if it already exists.

Comment: I've changed the code using `map` to a straightforward loop, because it wouldn't have worked as `map` is lazy.

Comment: @mkrieger1 well spotted.

Comment: Also you can't add easily add methods to built-in types so I've changed it to a normal function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unicodedata.combining`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.combining) to find out if a character is combining:

```py
def combine(s: str) -> Iterable[str]:
  buf = None
  for x in s:
    if unicodedata.combining(x) != 0:
      # combining character
      buf += x
    else:
      if buf is not None:
        yield buf
      buf = x
  if buf is not None:
    yield buf
```

Result:

```
>>> for x in combine("H̶e̕l̛l͠o͟ ̨w̡o̷r̀l҉ḑ!͜"):
...     print(x)
... 
H̶
e̕
l̛
l͠
o͟
 ̨
w̡
o̷
r̀
l

ḑ
!͜
```

Issue is that `COMBINING CYRILLIC MILLIONS SIGN` is not recognized as combining, not sure why. You could also test if `COMBINING` is in the `unicodedata.name(x)` for the character, that should solve it.

Comment: `COMBINING CYRILLIC MILLIONS SIGN` is category `Me` (enclosing mark) so is treated differently.  You could use `unicodedata.category(x).startswith('M')` instead, or see my answer for a 3rd party solution that implements glyph recognition.

Comment: are all enclosing marks combining somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd party `regex` module can search by glyph:

```py
>>> import regex
>>> s="H̶e̕l̛l͠o͟ ̨w̡o̷r̀l҉ḑ!͜"
>>> for x in regex.findall(r'\X',s):
...  print(x)
...
H̶
e̕
l̛
l͠
o͟
 ̨
w̡
o̷
r̀
l҉
ḑ
!͜
```